# Can't open jar file

Tags: java

I have a jar file that can't be executed when I double click it. It gives me this error:

> Error:Invalid or corrupt jar file.

I tried running it from cmd with two different commands:

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

and

```
java -cp myjar.jar package.mainClass.
```

Only the second command works. I'm using windows 7, and java version 1.7.0_45.
I checked my manifest file and it seems all right, so I don't understand what the problem is.

*P.S  I think it has something to do with the java version because I tried running the jar file in a machine with java 1.8 version and it worked.*

Comment: Show the manifest file and the structure in your jar

Answer (score 2):

Check if your *MANIFEST.MF* has a corrected *Main-Class* entry.

e.g.
Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass

Comment: I've checked it , it's there.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your myjar.jar
2. Find the **META-INF/MANIFEST.MF** and open it
3. Check if it has an entry **Main-Class: package.mainClass**

Comment: I checked the manifest file before posting my question, it has the reference to the main class.

Comment: You'd better show us the manifest file and the structure in your jar.